# centos7 wget over ssl : Unable to establish SSL connection

Tags: ssl, openssl, wget, centos7

I have tried upgrading wget, now it is the latest version,
but the problem still exists,
how can I solve this problem?
ps: this problem appears in the one pc which system use minimize installation then install gnome,but the another pc which directly selects gnome installation is ok(--!!!)

[wget gives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xe3oU.png)

[--no-check-certificate does not work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lvLY.png)

[openssl s_client show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UeMh6.png)

Comment: Please include textual information (i.e. all of your information) as text and not as image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the output you connect to 172.31.106.79 when trying to connect to www.facebook.com. This is not the IP address for facebook but an [IP address reserved for use in internal networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). It looks like that you have some DNS server which returns the wrong IP address for www.facebook.com. This might be some captive portal or it might be an attack or maybe some firewall blocking facebook or similar.

To fix the problem make sure that you are using a network which is not affected by this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command and then try : 
sudo yum update wget